# ValueError using enumerate in Pytorch (HDF5 data)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

whenever I'm loading my custom dataset (reduced CIFAR-10 to 512 features) and try to train it using the common methods, I run into a ValueError.
Since I've been handed a HDF5 file, I defined my custom Pytorch-Dataset as follows:

```
class HDF5Dataset(Dataset):
    # load the dataset
    def __init__(self, path):
        # load the csv file as a dataframe
        features = pd.DataFrame(np.array(h5py.File(path)['features']))
        labels = pd.DataFrame(np.array(h5py.File(path)['labels']))
        
        # store the inputs and outputs
        self.X = features
        self.y = labels
        # ensure input data is floats
        self.X = self.X.astype('float32')
        # label encode target and ensure the values are floats
        self.y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(self.y)
        self.y = self.y.astype('float32')
        self.y = self.y.reshape((len(self.y), 1))

    # number of rows in the dataset
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X)

    # get a row at an index
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.X[idx], self.y[idx]

    # get indexes for train and test rows
    def get_splits(self, n_test=0.33):
        # determine sizes
        test_size = round(n_test * len(self.X))
        train_size = len(self.X) - test_size
        print(test_size)
        # calculate the split
        return random_split(self, [train_size, test_size])
```

When I'm now trying to execute my custom defined (toy) neural network via

```
path = "resnet50_dim512.hdf5"
train_dl, test_dl = prepare_data(path)
print(len(train_dl.dataset), len(test_dl.dataset))
# define the network
model = MLP(34)
# train the model
train_model(train_dl, model)
```

I run into the following error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    349             try:
--> 350                 return self._range.index(new_key)
    351             except ValueError:

ValueError: 901 is not in range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-fd90001f6a16> in <module>
    156 # train the model
    157 print(train_dl)
--> 158 train_model(train_dl, model)
    159 # evaluate the model
    160 acc = evaluate_model(test_dl, model)

<ipython-input-37-fd90001f6a16> in train_model(train_dl, model)
    106     for epoch in range(100):
    107         # enumerate mini batches
--> 108         for i, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(train_dl):
    109             # clear the gradients
    110             optimizer.zero_grad()
```

The other functions that I'm using follow the standard approach, but maybe there are issues in that matter, so I'm including them below.

```
def prepare_data(path):
    # load the dataset
    dataset = HDF5Dataset(path)
    # calculate split
    train, test = dataset.get_splits()
    # prepare data loaders
    train_dl = DataLoader(train, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
    test_dl = DataLoader(test, batch_size=1024, shuffle=False)
    return train_dl, test_dl
```

And the training function where the error occurs:

```
def train_model(train_dl, model):
    # define the optimization
    criterion = BCELoss()
    optimizer = SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)

    # enumerate epochs
    for epoch in range(100):
        # enumerate mini batches
        for i, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(train_dl):
            # clear the gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            # compute the model output
            yhat = model(inputs)
            # calculate loss
            loss = criterion(yhat, targets)
            # credit assignment
            loss.backward()
            # update model weights
            optimizer.step()
```

It would be great if someone can tell me why this error happens, how to fix it or even circumvent working on the HDF5 file in this manner, or if it would be a better approach to first transform it into another file format in order to ease the training process.

All the best.

Comment: Could you print `self.X.shape` as well as `self.y.shape` at the end of your `__init__` in `HDF5Dataset`?

Comment: `train_dl` has a batch size of 32 and `test_dl` has a batch size of 1024. Change `test_dl` to be 32.

Comment: @yudhiesh I don't see how this is related, `batch_size` has nothing to do with the dataset's indices since it's related to the dataloaders. Plus, the error is raised when running the training. OP, please print `self.X.shape` and `self.y.shape`.